# How to alter BIOS in VAIO to allow for new battery?

Tags: 11.10, wine, battery, vaio, bios

I have a VAIO VGN-CR35G with 11.10 installed. I bought a new battery (not from Sony) with double the capacity but the BIOS is set for the old battery. The new battery came with a CD to update the `.dat` file with new information about the battery, but it's an `.exe` and does not work on VAIO.

I was thinking maybe I can alter the BIOS manually? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Boot Windows via Live CD/Pre-Installation Environment/Recovery Environment and run the executable from there. Don't try something different, this may cause damage to your notebook. Also you should only use original spare parts. There were too many exploding notebook batteries in the news in the recent years.